# Почему в хэш таблицах вставка и удаление занимает O(1), если по факту вся работа ведется в массиве, где эти две операции выполняются за O(n)?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, структуры-данных

Всем привет, будучи без пяти минут студентом, решил не тратить лето в пустую, поэтому решил прочитать книгу "Грокаем алгоритмы". При прочтении, задался вопросом, описанным сверху. Конечно, есть догадка, что в хеш таблице массив уже зарезервирован, из-за чего ячейки памяти массива не приходится, как либо изменять при вставке и удалении => и время выполнения будет постоянное. Но вопрос верна ли догадка или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Вставке и удаление в хеш таблицу не подразумевает вставку или удаление элемента из массива.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, в Википедии: [Хеш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Хеш-таблица) (если владеете английским, то переключитесь на него - там информации больше). При хорошей хеш-функции коллизий не будет и дело не дойдёт до операций со списками (где O(n)).

Comment: В данном случае операция вставки (и удаления) не предполагает "раздвигания" массива и переноса имеющихся в нем элементов. Это скорее аналог присвоения элементу массива некоторого значения, а операция `a[i] = j;`, как вы понимаете, не за O(N) выполняется, а за O(1)...

Answer (score 0):

вставка и удаление занимает О(1) потому что не смещаются элементы в массиве, все потому что информация о ячейках(ключах) хешируется, если я вставлю элемент с ключом 1 и другой с ключом 2, они в памяти таблицы не обязательно будут находится рядом. ключ ведь хэшируется и записывается в таблицу под индексом который представлен хэшем от ключа.

В общем все дело в хешировании!